# I am not able to login with Windows Authentication in SQL cluster scenario (Always on high availability)

Tags: c#, sql, windows-authentication, high-availability, availability-group

I am using SQL Cluster scenario with Always on high availability scenario. Everything works fine with the SQL Authentication but it is not working with the windows authentication.

The connection string I am using is

> DataSource=tcp:AG-Listener,1433;Initial
> Catalog=TestDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Persist Security
> Info=false;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultiSubnetFailover=True;

The main problem I am facing is that it shows the error "Login failed with the wrong user name" i.e.:"domain\huhassan-lp" and I am expecting it to login with "domain\h.Hassan".

I already added the following things in the app.config

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" /></system.web>
```

I already did user mapping with SQL access.

**My SQL Windows Authentication username:** domain\h.Hassan

**My Windows user:** domain\huhassan-lp

[image: SQL Exception]

Comment: Your config has `system.web` but you said `app.config`. Is this a web app running in IIS? If so what account does the App Pool use?

Comment: @Crowcoder I used system.web in my windows service app.config.

Comment: OK, what account is the service running as?

Comment: I didn't get your point properly. if you are talking about my windows service, It is logged on as a local system account.

Comment: Yes, I mean the service. I assume you are exposing a web service with your windows service? I'm not sure how impersonation would work in that scenario, but for a regular asp.net web app you would need to include the username and password in the identity element.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes you are right I am exposing web service with windows service. My windows service Log On the property is set as "Local System account". It is possible that it may give me another account?

Comment: Local system account will not have access to the database. There should be an account specifically created for accessing the resources needed by the application.